# how to get the next value of $(this)

Tags: jquery

How to get the next value of `$(this).val()`
I want something like this:`$(this+1).val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(this).next().val();
```

If you want the next value of what inputbox have then you can add 1

```
nextVal = $(this).val() + 1;
```

Comment: +1. few seconds makes many votes diff, I hate this system

Comment: i want $(this).val() + 1; but it's not working

Answer (score 6):

Try with `.next()` like

```
$(this).next().val();
```

Comment: You mean it's not `(that)`, followed by `(the next one)` and then repeats indefinitely? Dammit... my code's all wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `.next()`

`$(this).next().val()`

Hope helps